# difference between 'i' and 'I' in sed

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I thought `i` and `I` both mean ignorecase in sed, e.g.

```
$ echo "abcABC"|sed -e 's/a/j/gi'
jbcjBC
$ echo "abcABC"|sed -e 's/a/j/gI'
jbcjBC
```

However, looks like it's only for substitution:

```
$ echo "abcABC"|sed -e '/a/id'  # <--
d
abcABC
$ echo "abcABC"|sed -e '/a/Id'

$
```

It's really confusing.

Where can I find full reference of the meaning of regular expression for sed?

Comment: from [man sed](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.txt) : `i` is for inline modification, `I` is for case insensitive.

Comment: @MarcB I tried but can hardly find out, for example by searching "sed syntax", still don't know what the `id delete` in my second example mean

Comment: Thanks @Ploutox. The sed manual is a little bit long, can you tell me how to search difference of `i` and `I` in my second example? I'd like to know why my second example is outputting two lines: "d" and "abcABC"

Comment: @Ploutox `-i` (the command-line option) is for inline modification; it has nothing to do with the `i` flag used with the `s` function.

Answer (score 0):

`i` and `I` are indeed flags to the `s` command; they are not generally applicable to all uses of regular expressions in `sed`. The GNU man page is oddly silent on which flags `s` accepts (or even the fact that `s` accepts flags), so you'll have to look in the info page (run `info sed`).

Other uses of regular expressions are governed by the function in which they are used.

In your other examples, `i` and `I` are the actual `sed` functions applied to lines that match the regular expression `a`; `i` means to insert text. As far as I can tell, `I` is an unrecognized function and so ignored, leaving `d` as the function, deleting the line. (My interpretation of `I` may be wrong.)

Comment: `I` is seen as a case-insensitive modifier in the example. `echo "AbcABC"|sed -e '/a/Id'` returns nothing (the line is deleted).

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte you are right. Not a very good example, would be better if it's a multi-line output.

Comment: On the other hand, GNU sed doesn't seem to allow something like `echo "AbcAbc"|sed -e 's/a/x/iG'` instead of `sed -e 's/a/x/ig'`. So I assume that `I` is a (not documented) feature to allow a disambiguation for edge cases.

Comment: The inconsistency of this is not limited to GNU sed.  Per my answer, `'/a/Id'` does the same thing (i.e. deletes line, does not produce an error) in FreeBSD. So .. at least it's a *consistent* inconsistency!  :-D

Comment: My mistake, `I` is well documented in the GNU sed manual as the case-insensitive modifier. http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html

Answer (score 0):

The [sed man page in FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sed) in the section describing options to the `s` (substitute) command, says only:

```
    i or I   Match the regular expression in a case-insensitive
             way
```

Thus, the following are identical:

```
 s/a/j/gi
 s/a/j/gI
```

But that's only using `i` as a modifier to the `s` command.  In your second example, you're using `i` as a *command*.  The man page in this case states:

```
 [1addr]i\
 text    Write text to the standard output.
```

and at least in FreeBSD's sed, there is no `I` (capital-I) command.  So your sed script `/a/id` would (1) match lines containing an `a`, and if found (2) print the text "d".  Which is what you saw.

And since `I` is not a command, I would have expected an error, but my results match yours -- `/a/Id` appears to eliminate output.

Note that commands, commands, and completeness of documentation may differ depending on the variant of `sed` you are using.